# Altering Linewidth and Color for LineString Objects in Mapview

Tags: r, r-mapview

I'm working with reefs across a large area and trying to visualize them quickly such that I can pick a smaller subset to work on initially. To do this, I have taken my spatial points, transformed them to LineString to make the mapping quicker and then used mapview to display them. The code I have is below:

```
data_as_sf %>%
  filter(reef_name %in% subgroup) %>%
  group_by(.dots=c("reef_name", "reef_section")) %>%
  summarize() %>%
  st_cast("LINESTRING") %>%
  mapview()
```

A zoomed in sample of the mapview generated is here:
[image]

If anyone can provide advice such that I can

- make the lines bigger/thicker so they are more easily seen when
  zoomed out, and
- have the lines colored by the factor "reef_name"

it would really help.

Comment: For line width use argument `lwd`, for coloring use `zcol = "reef_name" `

Comment: Thank you for that, had been reading through the various other advice and documentation and didn't realize that the basic commands were still the way forward

Answer (score 1):

As answered in the comments by TimSalabim, have now updated the code to be

```
data_as_sf %>%
  filter(reef_name %in% subgroup) %>%
  group_by(.dots=c("reef_name", "reef_section")) %>%
  summarize() %>%
  st_cast("LINESTRING") %>%
  mapview(lwd = 3, zcol = "reef_name")
```

which works just right.